# Loop a cmd using shell script

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi3

How would I go about looping a command? For my Raspberry Pi I have to run a command that plays a audio file: `sudo ./fm_transmitter -f 100.1 -r star_wars.wav` when this stops broadcasting I need to input the cmd again to play it. I was wondering if your wonderful community help me make a script that everytime it finishes playing the audio it will just replay it using a .sh script!

Comment: `touch /tmp/fm_trans_playing; while [ -f /tmp/fm_trans_playing ]; do sudo ./fm_transmitter -f 100.1 -r star_wars.wav; done` (delete `/tmp/fm_trans_playing` to stop loop)

Comment: the file is located at /home/pi/Desktop/fm/fm_transmitter-master would you re-write it for this please.

Comment: Not much difference.all you need to do is substitute `sudo /home/pi/Desktop/fm/fm_transmitter-master/fm_transmitter` for `sudo ./fm_transmitter` above and use `/home/pi/Desktop/fm/fm_transmitter-master/star_wars.wav` instead of `star_wars.wav` to make sure the paths are absolute so the script can be called from anywhere without relying on being run in the `/home/pi/Desktop/fm/fm_transmitter-master` directory.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to run a command multiple times, using bash shell?](https://serverfault.com/questions/273238/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times-using-bash-shell) and [Continuously re-execute a command when it finishes in Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/361902/continuously-re-execute-a-command-when-it-finishes-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

This'll play the sound file eternally, (hit *Ctrl-C* to stop):

```
yes ./fm_transmitter -f 100.1 -r star_wars.wav | sudo sh
```

To run it in the background:

```
yes ./fm_transmitter -f 100.1 -r star_wars.wav | sudo sh &
```